# Tor is not loading onion sites? Why is this happening?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration, anonymity

When I try to open up an onion site, it says forbidden. I've looked at some sites for this question and it says you have to change your time zone. But what timezone? There's so many to choose from lol. Do you just change it by going to the windows setting?

Answer (score 1):

Most onion sites are run by amateurs and are thus going down temporarily/permanently all the time. This can be seemingly exacerbated by indexes not removing links that have been down for a significant length of time.

If you can access "big" onion services such as Facebook's (https://facebookcorewwwi.onion) or DuckDuckGo's (http://3g2upl4pq6kufc4m.onion/), then you're very likely trying to access onion services that are down. There's probably nothing wrong with your configuration.